# How do I select multiple elements of same type but different classes?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, queryselector

I have 6 inputs in a form, each with a class of .first .second .third .fourth .fifth .sixth respectively and I'd like to select them with vanilla JS but after trying with getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll, it still didn't work out.

here is my line of code:

```
document.querySelectorAll("form input")[0].value==""
```

How do I select all the elements with those classes?

Thanks in advance for any help rendered!

Comment: I suggest you give the elements a shared class, then use querySelectorAll on that shared class name. You can loop through the node list it returns to access all the elements with the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code `document.querySelectorAll("form input")` is basically getting what you want. However, you then do `[0].value==""` which is basically getting the first input and checking if it's value is empty. You could apply the class `sand` to all the inputs doing something like:

```js
function check() {
  var listo = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < listo.length; i++) {
    listo[i].classList.add("sand");
  }

  for (let input of listo) {
    input.setAttribute("required", "");
    input.required = true;
  }

  console.log(listo[0]);
}

sandify.onclick = check;
```

```css
input {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

input.sand {
  border: 1px solid sandybrown;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" /><br/>
  <input type="text" /><br/>
  <input type="text" /><br/>
  <input type="text" /><br/>
  <input type="text" /><br/>
</form>
<button id="sandify">sandify</button>
```

Comment: if I don't add [0.value there would be an error saying querySelector...is not a function

Comment: function check(){
  var listo = document.getElementsByTagName("form input");
for (var f = 0; f < listo.length; f++) {
    listo.classList.add("sand");
}
        document.querySelectorAll(".sand")[0].setAttribute("required", "");
         document.querySelectorAll(".sand")[0].required = true; 
}

Comment: I have the above function that I modified to assign the class "sand" to every input in the form but there's an error.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, if should sandify your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You an simply select by tag name:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName